# Can I remove an enum value with if it has been save with a JDO entity?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, enums, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

So I have saved a JDO entity that contains an value of MyEnum.

```
public enum MyEnum {
    MyValue1,
    MyValue2,
    MyValue3;
}
```

However now I need to remove at least one of the enum values. Will this crash JDO queries since a value that has been stored is no longer valid?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDO most probably uses [`Enum.valueOf(class, string)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) to instantiate enums. So in case of unsupported values it will produce `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Yes, as long as he stored it as a String and not an integer, http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/appengine/datanucleus/TypeConversionUtils.java#376

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add or remove enums in runtime, that is a Java thing, not GAE.

Comment: OP isn't asking that. He's asking if removing enum value (then compiling & deploying) will produce an error, since there might be value in database which does not map to changed Enum.

Answer (score 0):

Just like peter said, removing values from an enum will throw an error. However I just kept the old values and created a method getValues() which returns an array of current values and just use these. As users use the new version the old values will be automatically updated and can eventually be safely removed.